# Styling an svg in react using styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, svg

Does anyone know if this is at all possible. It appears that the only way I have of styling the svg elements appears to be an inline style attribute, passing the style as an object.

Comment: You can do so via styled.svg

Comment: Of course, it is possible, show us what you trying to style and how

Comment: @voiys, do you mean styled-components styled.svg`... ?

Comment: @MatthewPlayer yes

Comment: @voiys, I have tried that but can't get it to work; here is a codepen with the styling inline: https://codepen.io/mplayer78/pen/mdyPvOv?editors=0010 , now if I try to take the fill out of inline via a styled-component: https://codepen.io/mplayer78/pen/VwYaNap?editors=0010, and that's styling the circle directly.

Comment: I've also tried with style tags so I can create my own styled-svg but react doesn't like style tags and "dangerouslySetHtml" will show as styling in the devTools but is shown as crossed out, even though there is nothing below it. <b>Edit</b> If you open the dev tools on the second pen you will see where the dynamic class issued by SC is being ignored.

Comment: Dude your css is `fill: "red",` instead of `fill: red;`

Comment: Even out of the "" it makes no difference.

Comment: Turned the circle red for me, idk what else you want

Comment: In the second link? Mine shows as black.